# Missinng Operand For Loop Batch

Tags: batch-file

Below is a piece of code that is "supposed" to be used to, ping all IP's on my network and return the Computer name to an .txt file on my desktop. Every time I run it gives me "missing operand" error. Any help would be nice, gracias!

```
    @Echo Off
Title Getting all Computer Names from Network. . .
Color A
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Convert Current IPv4 Address to Variable.
For /F "skip=1 delims={}, " %%A in ('wmic nicconfig get ipaddress') do For /F "tokens=1" %%B in ("%%~A") do set "IP=%%~B"
SET "offsets=0.0.0.0"

For /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%A in ("%IP%") do (
   For /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%I in ("%offsets%") do (
      set /A octetA=%%A+%%I, octetB=%%b+%%j, octetC=%%c+%%k, octetD=%%d+%%l
   )
) 

REM Do a Ping Sweep To Get Computer Name.
For /L %%B in (1,1,254) do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims== " %%A in ('wmic /node:"%octetA%.!octetB!.!octetC!.%%B" computersystem get name /value') do set "Host=%%A"

REM Output Computer Name In Text File
Echo %Host% >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ComputerNames.txt"


pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  set /A octetA=%%A+%%I, octetB=%%b+%%j, octetC=%%c+%%k, octetD=%%d+%%l
```

`metavariables` are case-sensitive.

```
  set /A octetA=%%A+%%I, octetB=%%B+%%J, octetC=%%C+%%K, octetD=%%C+%%L
```

Comment: I learn something new every day (must have got the case right-by-accident all this time!). Also didn't realise you could set multiple values with `SET /A`.

Comment: Couldn't said it better myself! Seems that's all I was missing, thanks a lot!